# How to add a tooltip based on a DropDown list

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, kendo-ui

Basically I have a Kendo Grid where a couple of my columns also have Kendo DropDowns.
I would like to attach a ToolTip based on the value the user chooses from the "Instrument" dropdown.

Here's my grid javascript code (using MVVM pattern):

```
      tradesGrid = $("#tradesGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource,
        toolbar: [
            { name: "create", text: "Add Trade" }
        ],
        columns: [{
            field: "TradeId"
        },
       {
            field: "Instrument",
            editor: instrumentsDropDownEditor, template: "#=Instrument#"
        },
         { command: ["edit", "destroy"] },
        ],
        sortable: true,
        editable: "popup",
    });
```

and here's the Editor function for the Instrument dropdown :

```
 function instrumentsDropDownEditor(container, options) {

    var instrItems = [{     
        "optionInstr": "OPTION 22/11/2013 C70 Equity"
    }, {
        "optionInstr": "OPTION 26/11/2013 C55 Equity"
    },
     {
        "optionInstr": "OPTION 30/11/2013 C80 Equity"
     }
    ];

    var input = $('<input id="Instrument" name="Instrument">'); 
    input.appendTo(container);
    input.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "optionInstr",
        dataValueField: "optionInstr",
        dataSource: instrItems, // bind it to the brands array
        optionLabel: "Choose an instrument"
    }).appendTo(container);
}
```

and on my Html view file I'm starting with this idea :

```
  <span class="key-button"
              title="Instrument Details!!!"
              data-role="tooltip"
              data-auto-hide="true"
              data-position="right"
              data-bind="events: { show: onShow, hide: onHide }"
  </span>
```

Comment: you might be able to achieve what you are looking for with a jquery mouse over event http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/.  I don't know much about tool tips but I believe that have to be defined before hand so you may have to fake it and show a styled overlay or something like that

Comment: Useful jquery documentation. I'll consider that solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to rig up a jsFiddle right now, but I'm pretty sure this would work...

Init your tooltip in javascript, and specify content that is a function:

```
var myTooltip = "";

var tooltipWidget = $("#whatever").kendoTooltip({
  filter: "a",
  content: function (item) { return myTooltip; },
  ...
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Then on your dropdown widget, specify a change function handler that sets `myTooltip` to whatever contents you want.

```
var onSelect = function (e) {
    myTooltip = ...;
    tooltipWidget.refresh();
};

$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
  select: onSelect,
  ...
});
```

Or you can change the `title` property on your HTML element, if that is easier. However, the tooltip widget won't refresh its contents after it has been displayed, which is why you need to manually call `tooltipWidget.refresh()` after you change the contents.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know. Many thanks for that code.

Comment: and I'm wondering what i should do on the Html page. For example do I setup a div? <div id="tooltip" title="tooltip">test</div>

Comment: If you init the tooltip from JS, then all you need in HTML is the element that you are going to attach it to. It won't need a `title` attribute because the `content` is specified in the options, so it won't check the attribute. Of course you could use the `title` attribute if you want, instead of the `myTooltip` variable that I used in my example. Just update the attribute value instead of the variable.

Comment: how do I nicely post code examples here in this comment section ?

Comment: Your post was extremely helpful - thank you. I'm able to populate the "text" attrib of <div id="tooltip"></div> once I select an item in the dropdown. My challenge now it to format that text nicely using the kendoTooltip() widget. At the moment my dropdown text value is just display flat on my screen where I placed the <div>...pretty boring :-)